# Remote backup imap

Tags: backup, imap

I must archive to email with 1 server to 2 server temporarily and upload to 3 server. Why? My client is changing the server. Resigns from 1 server and want to buy a server 3. Server 2 is my. How can I make remote copies of IMAP?

old server -> my server -> new server...

Answer (score 1):

[imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) perhaps, although that copies one user's mail, not the entire server.

Comment: Ok, but server 1 and 3 it's shared server, no dedicated or vps. My server it's dedicated. Will it work?

Comment: imapsync works in that setting. Follow the link, have a look.